# Getting 415 Unsupported Media Type error while calling a SOAP web-service from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to invoke a webservice from PL/SQL code which will accept itemnumber as input parameter and will return about 8 output parameters, some are string while couple of will be in base64binay encoded PDF files.

When I am testing same WSDL from SoapUI it returns proper response.

But in my PL/SQL code I get 415 Unsupported Media Type Error. could you please help me to fix this, I am stuck in this error from last 5 days. thanks in advance.

Below is my dummy code, once it works fine, then I need to convert into a proper function.

```
 declare
        soap_request varchar2(30000);
        soap_respond CLOB;
        soap_respond_temp CLOB;
        http_req utl_http.req;
        http_resp utl_http.resp;
        l_resp XMLType;
        i integer;
        instr_start integer;
        instr_end integer;
        l_orgname varchar2(30000);
        l_description           VARCHAR2(250);
        l_long_description      VARCHAR2(1000);
        l_segment1              VARCHAR2(250);
        l_item_type             VARCHAR2(100);
        l_isbn                  VARCHAR2(100);
        l_match_score           NUMBER;
        l_pdh_id                NUMBER;
        l_cross_reference_id    NUMBER;
        l_soap_request     CLOB;
        l_soap_response    CLOB;
        l_soap_resp_raw    LONG RAW;
        l_buffer_size      NUMBER (10) := 512;
        l_substring_msg    VARCHAR2 (512);
        l_string_request   VARCHAR2 (512);
        l_raw_data         RAW (512);
        buffer             VARCHAR2 (32767);
        i                  NUMBER;
        eob                BOOLEAN := FALSE;
        resultvar VARCHAR2 (30000);
    begin
       --Item number 104PT is I/p parameter below to the SOAP webservice
      soap_request:= '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:grad="http://grades.web.spec.quality.asmorg.com/">
       <soap:Header/>
       <soap:Body>
          <grad:getGradeInfoForRM>
             <strRMItem>104PT</strRMItem>
          </grad:getGradeInfoForRM>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>';     
    http_req:= utl_http.begin_request
                ( 'http://112.18.28.38:81/Itemspec/ItemGradeWSPort'
                , 'POST'
                , 'HTTP/1.1'
                );
      utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml'); 
      utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Length', length(soap_request));
      utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'SOAPAction', ''); 
      utl_http.write_text(http_req, soap_request);
      http_resp:= utl_http.get_response(http_req);  
     --dbms_output.put_line('got the soap response');    
     dbms_output.put_line('Response> status_code: "' ||http_resp.status_code || '"');
     dbms_output.put_line('Response> reason_phrase: "' ||http_resp.reason_phrase || '"');
     dbms_output.put_line('Response> http_version: "' ||http_resp.http_version || '"');  
     DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_soap_response, TRUE);
    fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.log,'After create temporary');
     WHILE NOT (eob)
       LOOP
          BEGIN
             dbms_output.put_line ('before read_text');
             UTL_HTTP.read_text (http_resp, buffer, 32767);
             fnd_file.put_line( fnd_file.log,'Printing Buffer '||buffer);
             dbms_output.put_line( 'Printing Buffer '||buffer);
             IF buffer IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH (buffer) > 0
             THEN
              fnd_file.put_line( fnd_file.log,'Appending to l_soap_response using DBMS writeappend');
              dbms_output.put_line (' Appending to l_soap_response using DBMS writeappend');
                DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_soap_response, LENGTH (buffer), buffer);
             END IF;
          EXCEPTION
             WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body
             THEN
             fnd_file.put_line( fnd_file.log,'end of body');
                eob := TRUE;
          END;
       END LOOP;
    UTL_HTTP.end_response (http_resp);
    fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.log,'before XMLTYPE Call');
    dbms_output.put_line ('before XMLTYPE Call');
    l_resp := XMLTYPE.createxml (l_soap_response);
    DBMS_LOB.freetemporary (l_soap_response);
    fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.log,'--after XMLTYPE Call');
    dbms_output.put_line ('after XMLTYPE Call');
    resultvar := l_resp.getstringval();
    fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.log,'--after getstringval Call');
    fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.log,resultvar);
    fnd_file.put_line ( fnd_file.log,'End DateTime:- ' || SYSTIMESTAMP);  
       EXCEPTION
        WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('end of body');
      UTL_HTTP.end_response(http_resp);
           WHEN UTL_HTTP.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS THEN
      UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(http_resp); 
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('others eception  '||SQLERRM); 
    end;
```

Here is printed log messages:

Response> status_code: "415"
Response> reason_phrase: "Unsupported Media Type"
before read_text
before XMLTYPE Call
others eception  ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00229: input source is empty

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved now, problem was setting the header was not proper as per SOAP webservice type.

```
sys.UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(http_req, 'Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8');
   utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Length', length(soap_request));
utl_http.set_header (http_req, 'Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
sys.utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'User-Agent', 'Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)');
  utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'SOAPAction', '');
```

this clue about correct header type i.e. 'Content-type' and 'User-Agent', I got from SoapUI while looking at Raw tab.

Thanks,
Pradeep